# Help with Propositional logic disjunctive form

Tags: logic

I need your help to solve two propositional logic formulas

Put the following expressions in disjunctive normal form
using implication, equivalence and De Morgan's laws

a. P → ((Q ∧ R) → S
b. ((¬P ∧ Q) → S)

Here is what I got in disjunctive form and with the use of implication but I block for equivalence and De Morgan.

I tried to Simplify in disjunctive form: ￢P ∨ ￢Q ∨ ￢R ∨ S
Implication : P → (Q → (R → S))

thank you in advance

Comment: Correct. Formula $P → ((Q \land R) → S)$ becomes: $\lnot P \lor  (\lnot (Q ∧ R) \lor S)$. Thus, using De Morgan:  $\lnot P \lor  (\lnot Q \lor \lnot R) \lor S$

Comment: Thank you for your help but for equivalence do you have idea ? 
Thank

Comment: Equivalence with what?